# How to add dynamic field to django.core.serializers.serialize

Tags: django

I'm trying to export a queryset into json format. However, my query has a dynamic field (ie not defined in the model), and when I try to add it nothing shows.

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

My queryset:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).annotate(result=F('rate') * F('quantity'))
```

My call:

```
class ClassName:
    @classmethod
    def build__json(cls, queryset):
        geojson_str = serialize('json',
                                  queryset,
                                  fields=('result')
                                        )

        my_geojson = json.loads(geojson_str)
        return my_geojson

qs_json = ClassName.build_json(qs)
```

Is there a way to use `serialize` to do this? Or do I need to write a custom class?

PS: I'm not building a view, just trying to convert a queryset into a json.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `SerializerMethodField` in your serializer in drf, it looks much easier to add field that doesnt exist in models. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Answer (score 0):

I think that would solve you're problem

serializers.py

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    rate_quantity = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="rate_quantity_value")
```

models.py

```
    @property
    def rate_quantity_value(self):
        return rate * quantity
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how do I call the serializer providing my query? Something like:

```qs_json = Serializer(query)```

Comment: Serializer(data=query)